# K&R 1.19 exercise ("reverse" func)

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, kernighan-and-ritchie

Here is the task:

> Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the character string s . Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time.

Ok, now, my performing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIM 40

char line[LIM];
int c;
int reverse(char line[], int lim);
int len;

int main(void) {
    while ((len = reverse(line, LIM)) > 0) {
        ;
    }
    printf("\n      END OF THE PROGRAM     \n");
    return 0;
}

********** THE REVERSE FUNCTION*********
int reverse(char s[], int lim) {
    char rev[LIM];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';

    int r;
    for (r = 0; r < lim - 1; ++r) {
        rev[r] = s[i];
        --i;
    }
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < lim - 1; ++x) {
        putchar(rev[x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return r;
}
```

It seems to work correctly, but there are some bugs related to the output. 
For example:

**INPUT:** hello everybody    **OUTPUT:** ydobyreve olleh

**INPUT**: abc        **OUTPUT**: cba'

**INPUT**: ABC       **OUTPUT**: CBA'

**INPUT**: ABC ABC     **OUTPUT**: CBA CBA

**INPUT**: se se     **OUTPUT**: es es'

See? Some strange " ' " occurs in the end of output and I can't figure out any pattern why these "artifacts" get printed. It happens randomly (for me). Could you please suggest anything, what's wrong in the code?

Comment: Sorry, but that is horrible and way too complicated. I'm not even sure where to start! The empty while loop in main? Passing the global `line` into the function `reverse` but never using it anywhere else? Triple condition if the `for`?

Comment: @John3136 yeah, my code is not good yet, sorry. Well, about 'reverse':
1st 'for' - i get a line from input. 2nd 'for' - i declare an array and fill it with reversed line. 3rd 'for' - i print reversed line.

Comment: Why not "divide and conquer" make `reverse` just reverse a string: not read the string from and write the string as well. Then you can concentrate on doing one thing and just feed it some "precanned" input until it is working. Think about whether you just want to print the reversed string or reverse it inplace or reverse a copy of it.

Comment: The problem with the 2nd and 3rd loops is that they run until `lim - 1` which is the whole 40 characters. They should only run for the number of characters that are actually in the string. So in the 2nd loop, you should loop until `i` reaches 0, while incrementing `r` inside the loop. Then the 3rd loop can run until `x` is equal to `r`.

Comment: @user3386109 ok, thanks for you, i'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `reverse` function has problems:

- You should not store the newline into the `s` array as you do not want it to take part in the reverse operation.
- You should stop the subsequent `for` loop when you reach the end of the string in `s`, not run all the way to the end of the buffer.
- You should null terminate the `rev` array.
- You do not need to output the `rev` array one character at a time, use is as a string.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIM 40

int reverse(char line[], int size);

int main(void) {
    char line[LIM];
    int len;

    while (reverse(line, LIM) > 0) {
        continue;
    }
    printf("\n      END OF THE PROGRAM     \n");
    return 0;
}

/* THE REVERSE FUNCTION */
int reverse(char s[], int size) {
    char rev[size];
    int i, r, c, len;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    len = i;
    s[i] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rev[len - i - 1] = s[i];
    }
    rev[i] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", rev);
    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more modular solution. I wasn't exactly sure what K&R meant by "one line at a time". But this will reverse the string until it finds a newline. Then wait for the user and repeat.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int get_line(char s[], int limit);
int reverse(char to[], char from[], int l);

int main() {
    int size;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    while ((size = get_line(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        char revline[size];
        int len = reverse(revline, line, size);
        printf("%s\n", revline);
    }

    return 0;
}

int reverse(char to[], char from[], int l) {
    int i;
    int j = l - 2;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++, j--) {
        to[i] = from[j];
    }
    to[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

// read a line into s until limit
// return length of line
int get_line(char s[], int limit) {
    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < limit-1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Output:

```
testing one two
owt eno gnitset
three four
ruof eerht
five six
xis evif
```

Comment: The `getchar()` function may return `EOF` in some circumstances. In the event of a rare read error, `getchar()` will return `EOF` on successive calls, causing this code to enter an infinite loop. If a _user_ signals `EOF` from the keyboard, this code will continue seeking further input, and when input finally ends with a `\n`, the output will likely not be as expected.

Comment: I don't understand why the `get_line()` function is keeping the newline here; this requires `reverse()` to know about the extra character. Maybe `reverse()` would be better named `reverse_line()`; except it does not create a reversed line....

Comment: @exnihilo Cool. Let's see your solution.

Also, `reverse()` does in fact create a reversed line. `get_line()` keeps the newline because I wanted it to.

Comment: I don't need to provide a solution to gain the right to point out flaws in other solutions. You want to show OP how to use `getchar()` to fetch a line of input, so show them good code. You must test for `EOF` to satisfy "good code," and note that the accepted solution does this; this is a C idiom when looping over `getchar()`. Failure to test for `EOF` here leads to fragile code. I already mentioned why, but demonstrate to yourself by signalling `EOF` from the keyboard (CTRL-D on Linux) a few times in input, output will not be as expected.

Comment: "_Also, `reverse()` does in fact create a reversed line._" -- This is not true. A line ends with `\n`, and a reversed line also ends with `\n`. The problem stated above is to reverse a _string_. Your code does this, but keeping the `\n` from input means that `reverse()` must ignore that character. Passing a string that does _not_ contain a `\n` at the end will fail. `reverse()` expects a _line_, but does not return a line (merely a string). My intention was not to nitpick your answer, but to provide constructive criticism, which you ignored.

Comment: @exnihilo Hey, just a playful challenge. Didn't mean to imply that I don't appreciate the feedback. Anyway, I added the EOF check and in my opinion it works better than the accepted answer. Cheers!